# How to create a custom node in VisJS

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm creating a network of nodes and connection and came across VisJS. I tried to make some small working network graph and connect some nodes and this works fine. However, I need to create a custom node, this node should contain a title, some data and buttons that call a javascript(react) function. Is this, or something similar, possible in VisJs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vis.js network node customization: cards as nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462220/vis-js-network-node-customization-cards-as-nodes)

Comment: So is your question different in some way from the one I've mentioned? If so, I can answer about the different bits, but for now it sounds like I've already answered the same question.

Comment: Hey sorry, I completely forgot to reply. I decided to try another package(Konva) which works perfect for my usecase.