# vis.js html overlay not responsive

Tags: reactjs, charts, vis.js, vis.js-network, react-graph-vis

I am trying to implement vis.js network chart, where node having child elements, each child element clickable (not node as a whole). Tried below options to acheive the same.

- **HTML in SVG**

  This did not work, as it will get rendered as image and events added in the SVG's HTML elements do not work.
- **HTML overlay as in the reference http://jsbin.com/behagul/1/edit?html,output**

  Here, I added `onclick` event on the elements. and also added anchor tags in HTML overlay. none of the events/links work in the overlay.

Is there a solution for this requirement/issue?

Comment: see also discussion at https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/1965

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vis.js network node customization: cards as nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462220/vis-js-network-node-customization-cards-as-nodes)